# Sanitizing Query Results Data

Tags: 7

In my customized module, I have queried a database value, *Jocelyn D. Napiñas*. It contains *ñ* that causes my code to break. Is there any way I can display it? I tried the following code.

```
$data;  //Contains `Jocelyn D. Napiñas`

drupal_convert_to_utf8($data, 'us_ascii'); //Returns false

check_plain($data); //Returns ''
```

How will I display it as *Jocelyn D. Napiñas*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [drupal_convert_to_utf8](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/function/drupal_convert_to_utf8/7.x) it required **Requires the iconv, GNU recode or mbstring PHP extension** to work,  make sure **mbstring Php extension** installed(Go to `/admin/reports/status` and take a look at your unicode library) if not installed install it and try again

```
 drupal_convert_to_utf8($data , 'us-ascii');
```

if not worked  according to [mb convert encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) you can let Php detect encdoing with *AUTO*, so  use

```
drupal_convert_to_utf8($data, 'auto');
```

Also  I can suggest another solution for you

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $data);
```

Comment: @Qerjiuthn you are welcome, I getting happy when my solution save another guy time. we are here to help each other,

Answer (score 1):

Try `us-ascii` instead of `us_ascii`. That's how it's written in [unicode.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/7.x)